# string as key in map, custom the compare function

Tags: c++, c++11, comparator, stdstring, stdmap

I am using string as key value in map and trying to custom the comparison function. When I custom the comparison function by comparing the length the the strings, the map fail to tell the different strings with same size. The code is as followed:

```
class Solution {
public:
int findLUSlength(vector<string>& strs) {
    if(strs.size() < 2) return -1;
    auto cmpByStringLength = [](const string &s1, const string &s2)->bool
                        {
                            return s1.size() < s2.size();
                        };
    map<string, int, decltype(cmpByStringLength)> mpstringcount(cmpByStringLength);
    for(int i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++)
        mpstringcount[strs[i]]++;
    for(auto itmp = mpstringcount.begin(); itmp != mpstringcount.end(); itmp++)
    {
        cout << "itmp->first: " << itmp->first << endl;
    }
    return -1;
}
};
```

If my input strs is `["aba","cdc","eae","abcd"]`, the code will just output: `"abcd"` and `"aba"`.

Comment: Understand "this"? Understand what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the map fail to tell the different strings with same size.

Note that the comparator provided to [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is not only used for ordering, but also equality check.

> Everywhere the standard library uses the [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) concept, uniqueness
>   is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms,
>   two objects a and b are considered equivalent (not unique) if neither
>   compares less than the other: `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.

And [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) stores elements with unique key. Your compare functor compare `string`s based on their length, then for these `string`s with the same length only one of them will be stored. From the perspective of a `map<string, int, decltype(cmpByStringLength)>`, `"aba"`, `"cdc"`, `"eae"` are just the same `string`s.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the use of the compare function. I thought it is just using the compare function to decide the order of the key values. I read the compare function again: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/ So from p2, the function is also used to decide if the two elements are equal. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JianSun Yes, it uses the comparator for not only ordering but also equality check. If it uses something else fixed for equality check, like `operator==`, and `std::map` doesn't provide the method for specifying it, it'll be impossible to customize it.